# Calculate the intersection area of three types of polygons in QGIS

Tags: qgis, intersection, attribute-joins, spatial-join

I have three layers --

1. US Census tract boundaries (vector)
2. Radius of superfund sites (vector)
3. US Land Use (raster)

[image: attribute table of US Land Use]

So I only want the land cover types starting with 'Developed', and let's call it 'developed area'. What I want to do now is calculating the intersection of these 3 layers, i.e. the size of developed area covered by superfund radius for each census tract. I want the outcome product to be a csv, with columns of census tract, total developed area, developed area covered by superfund radius.

QGIS would be the most ideal software, but I'm open to R and Python. Just a little worried about the XML format of the land use map that might not be able to be recognized by R or Python.

Comment: Filter your layer by development area and then calculate the intersection between two vector layers in QGIS and then use that layer to do an intersection with your third layer.

Comment: so the land use map is currently raster, cuz it's downloaded as xml. Could you please show me how to filter the raster based on attribute table contents? Thank you!

Comment: Sorry I misread it, I thought you had three vector datasets. Can you provide a link to the raster dataset by edited your question? I'm not sure how you have attribute data associated with a raster layer.

Comment: yes. it comes from https://www.mrlc.gov/data/nlcd-2021-land-cover-conus as a zip file including xml and img. It seems only can be read into raster